# When x += y NEQ x = x + y | Can anyone explain?

Tags: javascript

You can just look at this Codepen (https://codepen.io/rcrooks/pen/abPYzVQ) or run this code for yourself:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
const numbers = [2, 4, 6];

let start = 0;
for (let x of numbers) {
  start += x + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = start;
</script>
  
<br>
  
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
const numbers2 = [2, 4, 6];

let start2 = 0;
for (let x of numbers2) {
  start2 = start2 + x + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = start2;
</script>
```

Why in the first script is += treated as string concatenation, but only on the first iteration?

Comment: You're using "+" to add the `<br>` string to the number, why would you expect it *not* to be string concatenation?

Comment: In the `+=` case, the right-hand side is evaluated before the `+=`. In either case the code is wrong.

Comment: but if adding "<br>" induces string concatenation, why are the last two interations treated as addition?

Comment: They're not. You'd see bigger numbers if it was doing numeric addition.

Comment: They're not though.

Comment: The second loop gives you different results than the first loop because `x += y + z` means `x = x + (y + z)`, not `x = (x + y) + z`.

Comment: If numeric addition were happening you'd see 2 6 12

Comment: but then why isn't the second row output 24?

Comment: good grief, **because you are shoving "`<br>`" in the middle of the string**.

Comment: Rather than adding `<br>` directly to your addition. why not do it on the `innerHTML`?

Comment: ok, so I should get 02<br>, then 02<br>4<br> shouldn't I?

Comment: Sorry, user2357112, my title wasn't exactly descriptive of the problem - you'll see if you look at the actual code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the same. Change

```
start2 = start2 + x + "<br>";
```

to

```
start2 = start2 + (x + "<br>");
```

Then it's the same.

Comment: ok, I see it's the same result with that modification, but I still don't understand how the 2nd and 3rd outputs come out to be 4 and 6.

Comment: nevermind. brain has come back to life ;)